# Spelling equivalences in search

Tags: feature-request, search

Related to the post [Add spelling suggestions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4525/add-suggested-spelling-for-jewish-words), why don't we have the search engine know that several different spellings (eg. Shabbas, Shabbat, etc.) are the same word and search of any/all of them when any one is entered? It seems to be a simpler solution to the same problem (which is a very real one, I had lots of trouble finding anything I hadn't seen before without guessing every spelling solution possible). Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it would be just a nightmare to code even if it was possible due to the practically infinite number of possible transliterations (to stay at your example: Shabat, Shabbat, Shabath, Shabbath, Shabos, Shabbos, Shabes, Shabbes, Šaḃåt)

Comment: @Kazibácsi Perhaps it could just use tag synonyms as its dataset

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know the coding of SE and the possibilities, but you'd still need to compile the list, and שבת was the easy part. Just to list a few possibilities: Ashkenazi or Sefard (or Artscroll's weird mixture), respect dagesh or not (if yes, for which letters), respect sheva na/nach, respect aspirated letters or not (if yes, for which letters). Try all with Ketuvot...

Comment: @Kazibácsi It wouldn't be perfect but it could get the most common possibilities and it would update itself as the community chooses to include more things. (kesubbos, kesubos, ksubbos, ksubos, ketubbot,ketubot,ktubbot,ktubot)

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems that Boolean search doesn't even work on MY and quite limited on SE in general

Comment: I wrote myself perl code that goes from transliteration to possible hebrew intended spellings to possible transliterations back in English so that you end up with a really long regular expression that would match the more common transliteration schemes for any word you were possibly transliterating in the original. (I once had my search engine allow hebrew:bereishis as a possible search term.) If usable, I'd be glad to share.

Comment: @Kazibácsi: But you can get 99% of what's out there with only a few possiblities per letter. (Remembering that a yud and thus a "y" might hide behind every "i" or "ee", etc...)

Comment: @MichaBerger The problem that the search engine of SE doesn't support Boolean operators...

Comment: But does it support regular expressions? Really, my guess is that MY's management doesn't have the power to just dig into the StackExchange code to do any of these things. But dreaming is nice.

Comment: (Totally off topic: I should probably make a WordPress plugin out of that transliteration to pattern-for-transliterations tool...)

Comment: @MichaBerger Asterisk seems to work, but nothing else. [Don't forget to tag me]

Answer (score 3):

This is a real issue. Tags help to some extent.

I guess however that it is a very MY-specific issue as most other sites use English (or another language but without the Hebrew-English transliteration issue). Since StackExchange (which runs MY) has many other sites to worry about, I doubt they will provide a MY-specific function which is not trivial.

But let's see as it would be a real service to the MY community if we managed this

Comment: relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange