# Creating table of contents of MY questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been worried for a while due to relatively low activity on Mi Yodeya, with some of you I have also discussed this issue. I think one possible solution could be to have closer ties with Sefaria, but linking old questions to their site may raise many issues. An idea I thought about is to create a table of contents that would list questions, where there is a reference to a certain verse or a page (and here we could add a Sefaria link). This could also help us with [search synonyms issues](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4547/15256). I would like to suggest something like this:

- Book of Bereishit: X questions

  - Bereishit – Chapter 1: Y questions

    - Bereishit 1:1: Z questions
      ...
    - Nechemyah 13:31: U questions
- Tractate Berakhot: V questions

  - Berakhot 2a: W questions
    ...

By scraping the source code of questions we could easily identify links, and with regular expressions we could find many other unlinked posts too. I have some experience in it, and would be happy to help. The difficult part seems to be to convince SE to cooperate with us to find a way to implement this idea. But a kind of special tagging could be a solution. I suppose it would greatly enhance search efficiency, because often you're learning Tanakh or Talmud, and would like to look for specific posts related to that verse or page. Again, I think it would be a big challenge, but it would be worth it. So I would like to hear your thoughts as well!

Comment: (Not the downvoter but) I'm not sure I understand the connection between low activity and linking to Sefaria.

Comment: Low ac tivity is multifactorial. Perhaps, if you want to investigate, you can make a questionnaire and study statistically.

Comment: @Alex I thought by linking to Sefaria, we could attract more users (see there the web pages section after clicking on a verse).

Comment: @kouty That's also a good idea, although most users, who have been inactive recently, won't show up on the survey either.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I am almost sure that people who are not active show sometimes what's news in the site.

Comment: @kouty If I can contribute, I'm happy to participate in preparing this survey, but I suppose we should have a separate post for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SE answer: Ain't no time for this.*

<sup>* I have contacted our friend at MY, [Yaakov Ellis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/487/yaakov-ellis), who expressed his doubts, whether they had any possibilities to allocate time for this feature request.</sup>