# Can we create a shulchan aruch, mi yodeya

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am curious, is it possible for us on mi yodeya to create a Shulchan Aruch Ha Mi Yodeya? Basically, the way it would work is that it would be a clickable feature on mi yodeya which would be ordered in the style of the Tur/Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim, Yoreh Deah, Even Haazer, Choshen Mishpat) and would have links to questions  in each area of Halacha in the shulchan  aruch. The way to fill it up would be users submitting their question, saying where they want it to go (like in hilchos shabbos Orach chain , Hilchos milah Yoreh deah etc.) and mods would review and approve/deny the entry based on how valuable they think it would be.

Comment: Isn't this what tags already are?

Comment: What do you see as the value of such a feature?

Comment: If you want to make a list of tags by shulchan aruch topic, that would do the same thing

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5362/15256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is a major organization project, layering on top of our existing collection of tags. As it is, if a person is interested in, say, interest Q&A, they can go to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags, type in "interest" or "ribis" or "ribit," and be directed to [lending-interest-ribbis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lending-interest-ribbis), our collection of Q&A on that topic (91 to date). They can then sort to see the newest material, questions needing answers, or the questions deemed most valuable by the community (score). This list is constantly updated every time anyone posts a question on this topic, posts an answer to one of those questions, or votes on one of them, without additional organization work by users or moderators (other than occasionally applying the tag if it's missing from a relevant question). It seems to me that the existing system provides nearly all the value of the project you're proposing, without the significant additional cost.

Comment: Of course, ours is by topic; where to find things in Shulchan Aruch is um ... not always quite so easy.